# How can I get the ID of a document in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have a database where cards are stored in cloud firestore my problem is that when I run:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
      {cards.map((card, index) => {

        console.log(card.id);
       ..
      ...
<View>
```

when I run card.id gets undefined I thought that Firebase provide a unique id for each document should I create a new property id ? or is there any way that firebase can handle it?

screen where I create my cards:

```html
import { View, Text, Button, TextInput, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import DateTimePicker from "@react-native-community/datetimepicker";

import React, { useState } from "react";
import { collection, addDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import db from "../database/database";

export const CreateTaskScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [state, SetState] = useState({
    title: "",
    description: "",
    date: new Date(),
    hour: new Date(),
  });

  const [showDatePicker, setShowDatePicker] = useState(false);
  const [showHourPicker, setShowHourPicker] = useState(false);

  const SetData = (key, value) => {
    SetState({
      ...state,
      [key]: value,
    });
  };

  async function HandlePress() {
    await addDoc(collection(db, "tasks"), {
      title: state.title,
      description: state.description,
      date: state.date,
      hour: state.hour,
    });
    navigation.navigate("TaskScreen");
  }

  const handleDatePress = () => {
    setShowDatePicker(true);
  };
  const handleHourPress = () => {
    setShowHourPicker(true);
  };
  const handleHourChange = (event, selectedHour) => {
    setShowHourPicker(false);
    if (selectedHour) {
      const currentHour = new Date(selectedHour);
      hour = currentHour.getHours();
      SetData("hour", hour);
    }
  };

  const handleDateChange = (event, selectedDate) => {
    setShowDatePicker(false);
    if (selectedDate) {
      const currentDate = new Date(selectedDate);
      SetData("date", currentDate);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Crear tarea</Text>
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Title"
        onChangeText={(value) => SetData("title", value)}
      />
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Description"
        multiline
        numberOfLines={4}
        onChangeText={(value) => SetData("description", value)}
      />
      <Button title="Select Date" onPress={handleDatePress} />
      {showDatePicker && (
        <DateTimePicker
          style={{ width: 200 }}
          value={state.date}
          mode="date"
          display="default"
          onChange={handleDateChange}
        />
      )}
      <Button title="Select Hour" onPress={handleHourPress} />
      {showHourPicker && (
        <DateTimePicker
          style={{ width: 200 }}
          value={state.hour}
          mode="time"
          display="default"
          is24Hour={true}
          onChange={handleHourChange}
        />
      )}
      <Button title="Save" onPress={HandlePress} />
    </View>
  );
};
```

that is the screen where I create each task document. here is the useEffect I use to fetch data (query snapshot):

```html
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(collection(db, "tasks"), (querySnapshot) => {
      const taskList = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
      setCards(taskList);
    });

    // Return the unsubscribe function to clean up the listener
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);
```

Comment: You haven't showed us how you create `cards`, so we don't know what's actually in it. Please edit the question to show enough code so we can understand what's going on.  If you didn't populate the `id` property of each `card`, then you can expect that there will not be one in your console log.  You will have to write that code yourself.

Comment: @DougStevenson question edited, I thought Firebase assigned an ID property for each document, anyway can you show me how can I generate the unique id?

Comment: It does not do that.  You have to write code to add that property, if that's what you want. The document ID is in the snapshot you got from the query.

Comment: thanks buddy turns out I forgot to add this line when fetching the data: id: doc.id,
        ...doc.data(),

Comment: If you have a solution, then feel free post it as an answer instead of leaving it in a comment.